# TypeError: can't assign a str to a torch.LongTensor pytoch

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'm trying to convert a list of strings into tensors but I get this error

```
lengths = [len(cap) for cap in captions]
    targets = torch.zeros(len(captions), max(lengths)).long()
    for i, cap in enumerate(captions):
        end = lengths[i]
        targets[i, :end] = cap[:end]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617871/how-to-convert-a-list-of-strings-into-a-tensor-in-pytorch

Comment: umm yeah  but it doesn't have solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's [`ord`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/ord) to convert characters to their unicode:

```
targets[i, :end] = torch.from_numpy(np.array(list(map(ord, cap[:end])))).to(torch.long)
```