# How to convert list of str into Pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

How do I convert a list of strings into a string/character tensor in Pytorch?

Related example with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

mylist = ["this","is","my","list"]

np.array([mylist])
```

Returns:

```py
array([['this', 'is', 'my', 'list']], dtype='<U4')
```

However, in pytorch:

```py
torch.tensor(mylist)
```

Returns:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-36722d81da09> in <module>
----> 1 torch.tensor(mylist)

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'
```

A tensor is a multi-dimensional array, so I'm assuming this is possible pytorch.

Note: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617871/how-to-convert-a-list-of-strings-into-a-tensor-in-pytorch) does not answer my question

Comment: [According to the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) there's no string type tensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no string tensor so you cannot directly convert to pytorch tensor of strings.

Alternative, you can convert the string to ASCII char values and save that as a Tensor.